# Rows to a Pie chart or a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

Sorry if a similar question is posted earlier.

I have a survey output which has rows like shown below

1. Agree
2. Disagree
3. Strongly Agree
4. Agree
   5.Agree
5. Disagree
   7 . Not Applicable
6. Agree
   ...
   ..
   ...

I would like to get either one of the following

1. A table that summarises the entire rows into something like this

Agree - 20%

Disagree - 30%

Strongly Agree - 10%

Or

2. A pie chart with above data showing %ge of people who agree and so on.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the output look like the following picture?

[image]

To get a Pie Chart or get the percentage of each object, we need to get the count of each object and the total account. The formula could help us.

=COUNTIFS(Data Range, One Object)/COUNTA(Data Range)

[image]

Then we could right click the cells of value proportion > Format Cells > Percentage.

Based on the data from E1 to F4, we could insert the Pie Chart. Click the symbol "+", check the box of Data Labels to show percentage.

[image]

Comment: Thank You for the solution. This is one of the solutions I expected